# not able to show captured image in imageview using image path

Tags: android

This is my camera activity that has a preview and a camera button that captures the image and saves it to the directory.

```
class cameraactivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private var filepath:String?=null
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cameraactivity)
}
private fun sendiamge(filepath:String){
    val intent = Intent(this, Imagerecyclerview::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("filepath",filepath)
    startActivity(intent)
}}
```

XML of camera activity->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".cameraactivity">

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/camera_capture_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:background="@color/secondary_orange"
    android:contentDescription="@string/camera_opening_button"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_camera"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

<androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
    android:id="@+id/viewFinder"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

image recycler view activity where I want to show the captured image in an image view.

```
class Imagerecyclerview : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var image:ImageView
private lateinit var imagefile: File
private lateinit var path:String
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_imagerecyclerview)
    image=findViewById(R.id.imageview)
    path = intent.extras!!.getString("filepath")!!
    imagefile= File(path)
    val bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagefile.absolutePath)
    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
}}
```

XML of image recycler view activity->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Imagerecyclerview">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

From the above code, I am able to capture the image and save it to the directory but I am not able to show the captured image in image view of imagerecyclerviewactivity it just loads the blank activity.

Comment: `filepath =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + photoFile` Please tell which path that is. Tell the value of variable filepath.

Comment: `From the above code, I am able to capture the image and save it to the directory but I am not able to show the captured image in image view` If that is true then you can just remove all that confusing code to take a picture. Enough is if you start with the path where your image is saved. Please do so as you posted much too much code. We dont like to dig through all that irrelevant code and gladly believe that you could take a picture.

Comment: @blackapps filepath is the path where the captured photo is saved.

Comment: @blackapps yes you are right that I can take pictures  directly from the phone's camera app but I want to create my own camera app using camerax API

Comment: Can be. But if you can take a picture already and you have already an image file somewhere on the device you should not bother us with code for taking a picture,. Only post the problematic codeL i.c the code where you want to display the image file in the image view.

Comment: @blackapps here is the problematic code that and the filepath is the path where the captured photo is saved.

Comment: `intent.putExtra("filepath",filepath)` Show in your code the value of filepath.

Comment: And before you call the intent use `if(!new File(filepath).exists()) return;`

Comment: And: `if(!new File(filepath).canRead()) return;`

Comment: @blackapps it didn't work. Still shows blank activity.

Comment: `val bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagefile.absolutePath)` bitmap==null ?

Comment: @blackapps can you please explain this what it means?

Comment: You should check if that bitmap variable is null.

Comment: @blackapps you are right my bitmap is null can you please tell me how to fix it??

Comment: The file that was choosen would produce a bitmap to big for available memory. It will have a too big resolution. First try to select a file with a small image (small resolution). Please test and confirm.

Comment: @blackapps thanks for your help. My issue is resolved. I was getting the wrong path that caused the error.

Comment: Hi, @blackapps I am facing one more issue can you please help.